# Angular CLI web worker generator

Tags: angular

I am trying to generate web-worker from angular cli and it's showing the following error message:

```
A merge conflicted on path "/tsconfig.worker.json"
```

Here is my tsconfig.worker.json file:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/worker",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "webworker"
    ],
    "types": []
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.worker.ts"
  ]
}
```

Generating web-worker file